# Vertx RxJava webclient client

Tags: java-8, vert.x, rx-java2

I am trying to consume a REST API using vertx and rx java, below is my code

```
import io.vertx.rxjava.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.rxjava.ext.web.client.HttpResponse;
import rx.Single;

public Single<HttpResponse<Buffer>> getLanguages() {
            WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions().setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.82 Safari/537.36");
            WebClient client = WebClient.create(Vertx.vertx(), options);
            Single<HttpResponse<Buffer>> single = client
                    .get("time.jsontest.com", "/")
                    .rxSend();
            return single;
        }
```

And my subscriber code in the main class is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Single<HttpResponse<Buffer>> single = new ITAPILanguagesImpl().getLanguages();
        single.subscribe(response -> {
            System.out.println("Received 1st response with status code" + response.statusCode());
        }, error -> {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong " + error.getMessage());
        });
    }
```

When I run the main method I get the following error

```
Jun 06, 2017 9:48:32 PM io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver trySuccess
Something went wrong Network is unreachable: no further information: time.jsontest.com/2404:6800:4007:807:0:0:0:2013:80
WARNING: Failed to notify success (time.jsontest.com/2404:6800:4007:807:0:0:0:2013) to a promise: DefaultPromise@5dcb32d8(success: time.jsontest.com/2404:6800:4007:807:0:0:0:2013)
```

I checked the url and it is working fine, only when I connect to this url using vertx webclient I get this error, what am I missing?
I have added the following artifacts as dependencies in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-rx-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a DNS problem in your environment.

Try switching to the JVM built-in resolver by adding this system property on the command line:

```
-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true
```

By the way, creating a Vert.x instance and a Web Client anytime you invoke your method is a bad practice. You should reuse a single instance of both.

Comment: Thanks man! I think the DNS problem was temporary, but thanks for the note on best practice.